# Unsuccessfully trying to deploy Angular 7 app to Azure

Tags: angular, azure, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an updated version of my App to Azure. I already have a Angular 4 version deployed (created with the original CLI 1.2.7). For reasons I can't remember I decided to create a new project with Angular CLI version 7.3.4 to 'upgrade' to Angular 7.

I first realized that I may have a problem when I tried to link the new projects github in my existing WebApps deployment but when that failed I figured I'd try it in a standalone version so I'm not disturbing users.

I can successfully deploy the App in the Deployment Center but when I browse to the site I get this error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Which reminded me that I need to have the Web.Config file as per Angular [guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml):

```
//NEW APP 
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is similar but not the same as the web.config file I have in my working version:

```
//OLD WORKING APP
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.bundle.js|.bundle.map|.bundle.js.gz|.bundle.css|.bundle.css.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Naturally I've tried that as well and I get the same result.

When I inspect the folder structure of my working app and compare it the new App, I think this is where the problem lies. As all my angular files and my web.config are stored in **dist{APP Name}** but in my working app all the files are stored in the wwwroot folder.

**New App**

[image: wwwroot of new App]

**Old Working App**

[image: wwwroot of old App]

Any ideas on how I can fix this, is there an app setting I can write to tell Azure where to look for the files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to export and deploy 'dist' folder to your App Service. Folder 'dist' is enough for your Angular application to launch.

```
ng build --base-href "/yourappname/" --prod
```

It creates dist folder and copy dist folder to wwwroot\yourappname. I believe that you may need index.html, index.htm or similar pages to bootstrap your application.

Try and let us know.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, the dist folder was exported and deployed. 

I also tried moved all my Angular files from wwwroot/dist/{APP}/ to wwwroot but no luck either there.

The error message I get in streaming logs is: 

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Comment: Just move all files inside dist folder alone to target app folder.